# PHP AJAX redirect not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

My goal is to get via ajax the return of a php file.
I have the following HTML form, I put the image to not break the indentation of the code.

http://prntscr.com/hegz9y

My function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pedir(){

            $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: "atualiza.estoque.php",
                data: $("#form").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                       alert("Busca efetuado com sucesso !");
            }


        });
}
</script>
```

My PHP:

```
 <?php
    include "../php/bddata.php";
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql="SELECT * FROM produto";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);

    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "id: " . $row["idProduto"]. " - Name: " . $row["nome"];
    }
    echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
    $conn->close();
?>
```

I can not see what's wrong with this code, I'd be grateful if anyone could help me. Sorry for my English, I'm not native.

Comment: there is no option like `method` but `type` instead , and you never told what problem you are facing or what error is in the `console`

Comment: problem solved :D Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `type` not `method`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post", // this one
    url: "atualiza.estoque.php",
```

Comment: I changed some more details and it worked. Thank you very much